# Xpath 1.0 expression to get the value of any request

Tags: xml, xpath

I am not sure whether this is possible or not? But I was wondering if we can a generic Xpath expression to get documentIdentifer value for any request.

**Request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Invoice Version="3.0">
         <Header>
            <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
               <DocumentIdentifier>0000001193567128</DocumentIdentifier>
            </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
            <ThisDocumentDateTime>
               <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">20150520T145204Z</DateTime>
            </ThisDocumentDateTime>
            </Header>
      </Invoice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Xpath **

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Invoice']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='ThisDocumentIdentifier']/*[local-name()='DocumentIdentifier']
```

I am able to get this value.

My question is root element keep getting changed, however format remains the same. All I need to get of `<DocumentIdentifier>0000001193567128</DocumentIdentifier>`.

Like if the root element is `<OrderCreate>` rather than using 
This Xpath

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='OrderCreate']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='ThisDocumentIdentifier']/*[local-name()='DocumentIdentifier']
```

Is there any other way of achieving the value?

Comment: Which language/library/tool are you using to run your XPath?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0 and using Xpath 1.0 and testing the Xpath in XMLSpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I need to get of `<DocumentIdentifier>0000001193567128</DocumentIdentifier>`

That would be `//DocumentIdentifier`, plain and simple.

You don't need to be overspecific in your XPath.

---

Since you use XSLT, please declare the namespaces that occur in your input document and avoid `local-name()`. Using `local-name()` like you do it (to "get rid of the namespaces") almost always qualifies as a bug. Declare namespaces and use them in your XPath, that's less typing, less error-prone and easier on the eyes.

Note that you don't need to use the same prefix as in the input, as long as you use the same namespace URI. In the following XSL snippet, I use `se` instead of `soapenv` for the SOAP Envelope namespace.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl=""
  xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:urn="urn:cidx:names:specification:ces:schema:all:5:0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="se urn"
>

  <!-- if you positively must be this specific -->
  <xsl:variable name="docId" select="/se:Envelope/se:Body/*/ThisDocumentIdentifier" />

  <!-- simpler/nicer is this -->
  <xsl:variable name="docId_nicer" select="//ThisDocumentIdentifier" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Will that take care of any namespaces problem? //DocumentIdentifier

Comment: @Kumar There is no "namespaces problem", you are just using them completely wrong. See modified answer. (Besides, `<DocumentIdentifier>` is in no namespace anyway.)